# Returning object from webapi to angularjs - not defined error

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, asp.net-web-api

Model:

```
public class Examplemodel
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
}
```

ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Action(ExampleModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Do Something 
       return Ok(model);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

AngularJs Controller:

```
app.controller('createController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.example = { Name: "" };

$scope.create = function () {
    $http.post('api/Create', this.example).success(function (response) {

        $scope.examples.push(response);        
    })
    .error(function (response) {
        var errors = [];
        for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                errors.push(response.data.modelState[key][i]);
            }
        }
        $scope.errors = errors;
    });
};


}]);
```

When I try to push 'example' object into 'examples' array I get an error saying "the response is not defined".

But when I try to extract individual elements from the response and store it into another variable it works. For example:

```
$http.post('api/Create', this.example).success(function (response) {
    var example = {};
    example.Id = reponse.Id;
    example.Name = response.Name;
    $scope.examples.push(example);   //This works     
})
```

So, why is the reponse from the server not defined? How can this be solved without creating a variable object?

Comment: try to check all values of response in console.log

Comment: Interesting.  There is definitely some inconsistency in your observation. 
Because when your extract individual elements, the response is defined and your are able to access it. But when you try to push it into an array it is not defined.

Comment: I thinks response.data.Id will return your result Id.

Comment: @KashifMustafa Ya I checked the console too. They match except for the variable name difference: 'response' , 'example'

Comment: can you make a plunker of it, so we can play with it and solve your strange issue

Comment: STRANGE: I don't know how but suddenly the error went away. Now it is working without the extra step.